# Do i have to create every table in MYSQL sequelize in node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Currently my current company is using PHP + MYSQL and they have over 100 tables in MYSQL.

My job is to create a basic node.js API and sort of communicate with their existing database.

Do i need to create 100 models if node.js were to communicate with existing 100 tables in MYSQL?

Answer (score 1):

**It Depends :**

If you need to query upon each and every table **with ORM structure** , yes in that case you have to create model for each table

If you need to query some of the table then create models for those table only

---

Another way ( **Not suggesting** ) :

Just **[Run raw queries](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html)** with sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

you can go with database first approach. there is a module for that.

it will automatically generate models for SequelizeJS via the command line.

[Sequelize-auto](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto)

Disclaimer: Personally never use this package.